# Siemens MC39i GSM Modem send SMS linux

Tags: php, sms, gsm, modem, gateway

I recently bought a serial modem "Siemens MC39i GSM Modem" in an attempt to setup a script that would send SMS to customers.

Anyway its all connected up I believe it is /dev/ttyS0 and I have tried running the following code which I found elsewhere:

```
echo "AT

AT+CMGF=1

AT+CMGW="+775557"
> A simple demo of SMS text messaging.
+CMGW: 1


AT+CMSS=1
+CMSS: 20
" > /dev/ttyS0
```

The modem light flashes but nothing happens I dont receive an SMS, also no output is returned either.

Does anyone have any advice who may have done something like this before?

Thanks!

Comment: That is not valid PHP code. So I won't expect that it works in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with any mobile phone connected via the serial port or USB. And while you certainly can interface to it via AT commands, you shouldn't really do it manually.

The prefered way is most certainly to use `gnokii` for sending sms:

```
exec('echo "A simple demo." | gnokii --sendsms +775557 --report');
```

And there are likely SMS libraries for PHP too, especially for the special charset encoding required. (But you can inspect whatever gnokii sends to the serial devfile.)